# How to hide "Task Manager" in menu

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, taskmanager

For the menu that appears when you press CNTL-ALT-DEL, how do you hide "Task Manager" entry? Is there a registry setting that I can disable, etc? I would like to include a line in a batch file to hide, thanks.

[image: cntl-alt-del-menu]

Answer (score 1):

The registry path to customize ctrl+alt+del options is:-

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

Double click on value/s you want to hide & set its value as 1. This will disable the that option from appearing.

The Keys are:-
1) DisableLockWorkstation
2) HideFastUserSwitching
3) NoLogoff
4) DisableChangePassword
5) DisableTaskMgr

If any of them don’t exist and you want to hide it then you need to add it first.
To add value - right-click on any blank white space on the right side and create a New DWORD value name, as mentioned above, and set its value to 1.

To revert back, you may switch the value, back to 0.

This can work on Windows:- 7/8/10

Comment: This is a programming site, so your answer should ideally include the code required to make the specific registry change requested.